# ffmpeg fade to specific color values over time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing, filter, alpha

I have a background image that I'm trying to fade to specific color values using this filter: `lutrgb=enable='gte(t,3)':'r=0.3*val:g=0.3*val:b=0.3*val'`

This almost works, but it changes the values instantly.  How do I get it to fade to those values gradually over time?

Comment: Your example doesn't alter alpha but the color channels. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I was messing with alpha earlier and the word "opacity" stuck. I'm simply trying to get the background image to partially fade/darken, not become transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lut` filter expressions don't work with time. `geq` does.

```
geq=r='(1-0.7*min((T-S)/D,1))*p(X,Y)':g={the same as r}:b={the same}:enable='gte(t,S)'
```

`S` should be your start time in second. `D` is duration for the change in colours. `T` and `p(X,Y)` are variables and should be kept as is.

Comment: Gives me an error. I tried both substituting each S with the start time and not substituting. `[Parsed_geq_0 @ 0x7fa6ab5007c0] [Eval @ 0x7fff576460e0] Unknown function in 'S)/D,1))*p(X,Y)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fa6ab413a80] Error initializing filter 'geq' with args 'r=(1-0.7*min((T-S)/D,1))*p(X,Y):g=(1-0.7*min((T-S)/D,1))*p(X,Y):b=(1-0.7*min((T-S)/D,1))*p(X,Y):enable=gte(t,3)'`

Comment: `S` and `D` have to be substituted with numerical values.

Comment: I got it working, however it's slowing the rest of the encoding process to a crawl. How do I get it to resume normal encoding speed?

Comment: Change enable to `between(t,S,S+D) ` And add your lut filter for `gte(t,S+D)`

Comment: I get an error trying that. Here's what I have: `geq=r='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':g='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':b='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':'between(t,3,3+3)',lutrgb=enable='gte(t,3+3)'`

Comment: You have to keep the `enable=` before `between` (and I assume you've simply omitted the lut exprs for brevity. They should be specified)

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks for your patience. I actually had to use `gt` instead of `gte`, otherwise I would get a frame of overlap where the image was extra darkened. Final command that works: `geq=r='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':g='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':b='(1-0.7*min((T-3)/3,1))*p(X,Y)':enable='between(t,3,3+3)',lutrgb=enable='gt(t,6)':'r=0.3*val:g=0.3*val:b=0.3*val'`